# Java MySQL COUNT query in case of a relation of two rows

Tags: java, mysql, count

I am developing a web application in java.
There I use several MySQL tables.

One of them marks 'relationships' between two objects.
So i created a table:

```
id  username    relation    timestamp
1   user1       user2   2014-11-18 12:20:03
2   user2       user1   2014-11-18 12:20:03
```

a user is related to another when this user marked the other user as 'related' AND the second user marked the first as well.

in case of

```
id  username    relation    timestamp
3   user1       user3   2014-11-18 12:20:03
```

there is no relationship.

I can count the amount of one-sided relationships of a user. But now I need to count the amount of real (two-sided) relationships of one user.
Can I use the COUNT command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assumming that there is an unique constraint on columns `username + relation`, so there it is impossible to enter the same relation twice, e.g

```
id  username    relation    timestamp
1   user1       user2   2014-11-18 12:20:03
2   user1       user2   2014-11-18 12:20:03
```

Under the above assumption, in order to count "two-sided" relations of a particular user, a semi join can be used:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM table1 x1
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM table1 x2
  WHERE x1.`username` = x2.`relation`
    AND x1.`relation` = x2.`username`
)
AND x1.`username` ='user1';
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67db14/2

---

I am also assuming that there is some constraint on the table that prevents from entering self-related users, for example:

```
id  username    relation    timestamp
1   user1       user1   2014-11-18 12:20:03
```